# For what value of $b$ is $g(x)$ continuous at every $x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
b^2-x^2,  & x<2 \\
2(b-x), & x\ge 2
\end{cases}
$$
I'm having trouble with continuity and don't quite get how to solve this or where I should start.

Comment: The critical value is $x=2$. Plug it in both expression and determine the $b's$ for which both expressions coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction of $g$ on $(-\infty,2)$ and $(2,+\infty)$ is continuous since it is the restriction of a polynomial function on each interval. You have to check the continuity at $2$.

$b^2-4=2(b-2)$ and solve the quadratic equation $b^2-2b=0$, $b=2$ or $b=0$.